# How to enable USB Tethering without forcing me to use mobile data plan?

Tags: mobile-data, usb-tethering, t-mobile

I wanted to tether my phone's connection to my pc via this old phone that I found. There's a setting for USB tethering, but when I turn it on, it says to turn on the mobile data? I went to the help thingy in the settings for the USB tethering and this showed what seen on the images below. Is there no way to stop forcing me to turn on my data just to share my connection to my pc?

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Is it possible that the device that should be for tethering is a T-mobile (or a different MNO) branded device? Some MNOs restrict the tethering functionality. Also when asking question please always include what device (manufacturer + model name) you are talking about. Android devices are some times heavily modified by the manufacturer. Also it is always good the include the Andorid version it is running on.

Comment: Apologies if I've misunderstood your explanation. Tethering means to connect a device (in your case a PC) to your phone via USB cable so that the PC can use the phone's internet connection. Without data, your phone has no internet connection. I suspect you want to transfer files between the phone and the PC. If that is so, you don't need tethering. Just connect using USB cable and Android should offer options via notification what the connection is for (use media, transfer files etc) and the PC will also show the USB connection and offer options in the notification area.